# How to publish NPM packages on GitHub and allow them to be downloaded without authentication?

Tags: angular, github, npm, package, publish

I recently started to create some NPM packages to use in the company where I work.

We have already published two component packages for Angular.
However, when we went to use the packages, the Azure DevOps build pipeline was unable to download the packages. Accusing problems with authentication, causing the error and pipeline break.

The quickest solution (since we are in Scrum Sprint) was to publish the same packages in the NPM Registry.

Is there a way to publish the GitHub organization's packages in a public way?

---

Searching on Google, I found this:

- https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/npm-install-from-github-leads-to-401-GPR-NPM-registry-for-public/m-p/44463

.

---

> Packages from my organization:

- GitHub (GPR): https://github.com/orgs/Viceri/packages
- NPM Registry: https://www.npmjs.com/~viceri?tab=packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible as per [this post](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/Download-from-Github-Package-Registry-without-authentication/td-p/35255) on the GitHub Community.

The only way you will be able to use this is to add authentication in your pipeline

Comment: It does not make sense to me that packages are not public, as GitHub is an Open Source code repository. But anyway, thanks! 

Comment: Yeah it is annoying. Hopefully they change it soon.